# How to store a h2o function as an h2o object for deployment?

Tags: python-3.x, h2o, gbm

I used

```
h2o.predict_leaf_node_assignment(model, frame)
```

to get the `leaf node assignments` of my `gbm` model. Is it possible that I store this function as an `h2o`-object and then use it for deployment on new data entries?

Comment: What do you mean by "h2o object"?  Do you want to deploy using a binary model or a MOJO/POJO model?

Comment: Is it possible to deploy it as a mojo/pojo model? How can I get this function mechanism for the new data under deployment? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Rather than h2o.predict_leaf_node_assignment(), I would use h2o.download_mojo() [or pojo] and use the downloaded object.

Here are a couple of git repositories with examples:

- https://github.com/h2oai/app-mojo-servlet
- https://github.com/h2oai/app-consumer-loan

And here are pointers to the relevant documentation:

- http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-genmodel/javadoc/index.html
- http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/productionizing.html

Mojos are easier to work with, so my preference would be to use those instead of pojos if it works for you.